# Find most common element in array

Tags: c#

I have a string array that can contains 1 or more elements with various string values.  I need to find the most common string in the array.

```
string aPOS[] = new string[]{"11","11","18","18","11","11"};
```

I need to return `"11"` in this case.

Comment: shouldn't it be `string[] aPOS = new string[]{"11","11","18","18","11","11"};`

Answer (score 19):

Try something like this using LINQ.

```
int mode = aPOS.GroupBy(v => v)
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
            .First()
            .Key;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like using LINQ or are using e.g. .Net 2.0 which does not have LINQ, you can use foreach loops

```
string[] aPOS = new string[] { "11", "11", "18", "18", "11", "11"};
        var count = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (string value in aPOS)
        {
            if (count.ContainsKey(value))
            {
                count[value]++;
            }
            else
            {
                count.Add(value, 1);
            }
        }
        string mostCommonString = String.Empty;
        int highestCount = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in count)
        {
            if (pair.Value > highestCount)
            {
                mostCommonString = pair.Key;
                highestCount = pair.Value;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with LINQ, the following is untested,  but it should put you on the right track

```
var results = aPOS.GroupBy(v=>v) // group the array by value
                     .Select(g => new { // for each group select the value (key) and the number of items into an anonymous object
                                   Key = g.Key,
                                   Count = g.Count()
                                   })
                      .OrderByDescending(o=>o.Count); // order the results by count

// results contains the enumerable [{Key = "11", Count = 4}, {Key="18", Count=2}]
```

Here's the official [Group By documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx)